# Blocking inbound emails with google admin api

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk

We would like to block a malicious user from sending our employees emails automatically through google admin api.

For example, when we notice that user `hacker@malicious.com` sends our employees phishing emails, we would like to block it (`malicious` might be very similar to our domain name).

We can't find any option how to do this on [admin-sdk](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk).

However, we know that there are options to do this manually, since when we go to `Apps-> Google Apps -> Settings for Gmail -> Advanced Settings` on [admin.google.com](https://admin.google.com), we see several options to achieve this:

> `Blocked senders`: Block or approve specific senders based on email
>   address or domain.
>   `Content compliance`: Configure advanced content filters based on
>   words, phrases or patterns.
>   `Routing`: Routing begins once you start delivering email to Google's
>   servers.
>
> `Receiving routing`: Set delivery routes for inbound messages, and for
>   messages received from internal addresses.

How can we block inbound emails with admin sdk?

Answer (score 1):

There's no API to manage blocked senders list in the Control Panel. However, you can [create filters for your users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#creating_a_filter) using the Email Settings API.